# How remove substring from a particular character in string in scala

Tags: scala

I want to remove substring after 'Y' character. Final output should be EBAY in all three cases below. But output coming as EBAYSK.

```
object AndreaTest extends SparkSessionWrapper {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  var string1= "EBAY-SK"
  var string2= "EBAY SK"
  var string3= "EBAY- SK"
  val finalString1 = string1.replaceAll("[-]/' '", "")
  val finalString2 = string2.replaceAll("[-]/' '", "")
  val finalString3 = string3.replaceAll("[-]/' '", "")
  println(finalString1)
  println(finalString2)
  println(finalString3)
}
```

Comment: You are replacing in code and asking substring,just google substring in scala

Answer (score 3):

try this regex

```
val strings = List("EBAY-SK", "EBAY SK", "EBAY- SK", "EBAY", "EBAYEBAY")

val pattern = """([^.]*?Y).*""".r

strings.foreach(a => pattern.findAllIn(a).matchData foreach {
    m => println(a + " -> " + m.group(1))
})
```

output:

```
EBAY-SK -> EBAY
EBAY SK -> EBAY
EBAY- SK -> EBAY
EBAY -> EBAY
EBAYEBAY -> EBAY
```

Answer (score 1):

You either use a working pattern, i.e. replace - or \s (space) plus everything following it:

```
val finalString1 = string1.replaceAll("[-\\s].*", "")
val finalString2 = string2.replaceAll("[-\\s].*", "")
val finalString3 = string3.replaceAll("[-\\s].*", "")
```

Or just use `substring` instead of `replaceAll`:

```
val finalString1 = string1.substring(0, 4)
val finalString2 = string2.substring(0, 4)
val finalString3 = string3.substring(0, 4)
```